# C# Displaying total amount of money in a class instance

Tags: c#

I'm taking an online c# class and it asked me to fill in some of the blanks and I figured out everything expects this:
In my console app I added up a different amount of money and now I'm trying to display them.

My end result should look like this:

[image: Image showing result]

My code:

```
namespace CashRegister
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare a new CashRegister object
            CashRegister myRegister = new CashRegister ();

            // add several dollar amounts
            myRegister.add (20.00);
            myRegister.add (15.50);
            myRegister.add (3.75);

            // display the current cash balance
            Console.WriteLine("The register has: $" + myRegister.????());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    // CashRegister object definition
   class CashRegister
   {
      // declare a property (class variable)
      double cash = 0.0;

    // define an add() method that takes one double "amount" parameter
    public void add(double amount)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Adding $" + amount);
         cash += amount;
      }

        // define a report() method that returns one double value
        public double report()
             {
                     return cash;
             }
   }
}
```

What do I insert into the question mark to get the final result to be the same as the image?

Comment: `myRegister.report()`

Comment: I also recommend reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions .

Comment: just as an aside, any course that uses double to store money values is leading you astray.  There is a much better type called "decimal" for doing this.  double causes many surprises due to the way it is implemented, it's never never never a good way to store exact values

Comment: @Keith Nicholas Yea the C# course i'm taking is such a shame. Their lessons suck compared to just basic google searches and I took there html/css course last year and it was a great course. The way the course is designed is like they are giving a review info instead of lessons because a lot of the stuff they taught I had to google search other things about c# to understand what they were saying. The name of the company is CompuScholar BTW.

Comment: Don't use `double` for currency amounts - it's for scientific values. Use `decimal` for doing money calculations - it's designed to avoid rounding issues for decimal numbers (hence the name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `report()` method you already have returns the value of `cash`. All you need to do is call it:

```
Console.WriteLine("The register has: $" + myRegister.report());
// Here ---------------------------------------------^
```